# If $f$ is entire and does not take values in $|w|\leq 1$, then $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Magnitude of differentiable complex function $f(z)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149717/magnitude-of-differentiable-complex-function-fz)

I have the question

> Let $f(z)$ be an entire function and assuming $f(z)$ does not take values in $|w|\leq 1$, show that $f(z)$ is identically constant.

I tried to prove with Liouville's theorem, but I couldn't find the correct implementation., because I did not understand the meaning of "$f(z)$ does not take values in $|w|\leq1$".  Could you help me please? If you can, could you give the proof?

Thanks.

Comment: If $f(z)$ does not take values in the unit disc, then it does not come arbitrarily close to $0$. What does that mean for $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}$?

Comment: yes your right . ı got solution from there. thanks

Comment: **Picards theorem :** If $f$ is a non-constant entire function on $\mathbb{C}$ then then $f$ assumes all the values in $\mathbb{C}$ except possibly one value. Since your function misses out on all values inside the unit disc. It is automatically a constant function.

Answer (score 2):

If $|f(z)|\not\leq 1$, then $|f(z)|>1$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$.  Take reciprocals of the inequality.  Then you should see how to apply Liouville to $\frac{1}{f(z)}$.